# angular2 router invalid path then do redirect Error

Tags: angular

How to redirect if user type some random url? I'm using @angular2/router to do my route paths. The code below throws an error saying "Cannot match any routes: 'url'". I don't think I need to put `/` in front of *path as I've already set my baseurl in the html header.

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '*path', redirectTo:''},
];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add `**` to path,

```
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
```

docs : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Then that means I will have to create that component? isn't there a redirectTo instead? Also isn't that wildcard will take any path and redirect to somewhere?

Comment: It will match to all non existing path. You can use redirectTo as well.

Comment: No you dont have to create a new component. Simply give existing component reference where you want to redirect users. This route is for when router can't find request route.